# If $D$ is bounded and $f$ is $\alpha$-Hölder continuous, then $f$ is also $\beta$-Hölder continuous for $\beta \in (0,\alpha]$

Tags: real-analysis, holder-inequality

> If $D$ is bounded and $f$ is $\alpha$-Hölder continuous in $D$, then $f$ is
>   also $\beta$-Hölder continuous for $\beta \in (0,\alpha]$

Couldn't I just use the fact that I have already proven that every $f$ that is $\alpha$-Hölder continuous, is uniformly continuous. Uniform Continuity encompasses the entire interval.

Comment: What is $D$????

Comment: No. Uniform continuity does not imply any  Holder condition.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich but vice versa.

Comment: $D$ is an arbitrary bounded set.

Comment: "But vice versa": I don't know what your point is. Yes, $Lip_\alpha$ implies uniform continuity. But that does not in turn imply $Lip_\beta$, so you cannot just use uniform continuity to show $Lip_\alpha$  implies $Lip_\beta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D$ be bounded, then there exists $M>0$ s.t. $|x|\leq M$ for all $x\in D$. Therefore, 
\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(y)|\leq K|x-y|^\alpha &=K|x-y|^{\alpha -\beta }|x-y|^\beta\\ & \leq K(|x|+|y|)^{\alpha -\beta }|x-y|^\beta \tag{$*$}\\ 
&\leq K(2M)^{\alpha -\beta }|x-y|^\beta ,
\end{align}
where $(*)$ holds because $\alpha -\beta >0$.

Comment: (i) This doesn't really answer the question that was asked. (ii) You might be specific about where the fact that $\beta<\alpha$ is  used...

Comment: (i) It does answer. The question is $\alpha -$Holder implies $\beta -$Holder. (ii) In the last inequality and in the fact that $|x-y|^{\alpha -\beta }$ is well defined for all $x,y\in D$. @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: (i) No. You (almost) explained why $Lip_\alpha$ implies $Lip_\beta$. but that's not what the OP asked! The question was whether this follows from thhe fact that $Lip_\alpha$ implies uniformly continuous.

Comment: (ii) What? We only need the inequality for $x\ne y$; if $x\ne y$ then $|x-y|^{\alpha-\beta}$ is well-defined regardless of whether $\alpha-\beta>0$.

Comment: (ii) In fact the reason you need $\beta<\alpha$ is to show that $|x-y|^{\alpha-\beta}\le\text{diam}(D)^{\alpha-\beta}$. (Note for example $1<2$ but $1^{-1}>2^{-1}$.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: That's why I wrote in my previous comment : "(ii) **In the last inequality AND...**". I'm not really sure that your intervention is really constructive here...

Comment: I can't use $\text{diam}$...

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic: Could you elaborate ? What mean "$D$ is bounded" for you ? If you can't use the fact that $D$ is bounded, why do you mention it ?

Comment: You could use it in an other way...But diam hasn't been lectured yet.

Comment: I edited my answer @ParabolicAlcoholic

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out myself.