# If $f \in L^1(\Bbb T)$ is Lipschitz-continuous on $I \subset \Bbb T$ then $\widetilde f$ is $\alpha$-Hölder-continuous for all $\alpha < 1$ on $I$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $f \in L^1(\Bbb T)$ be Lipschitz-continuous on an interval $I \subset \Bbb T$. Then, $\widetilde f$ is Hölder-continuous with constant $\alpha$ for all $0 < \alpha < 1$ on $I$.

---

I'm trying to show the above result. $\widetilde f$ is the conjugate function of $f \in L^1(\Bbb T)$, defined as follows. First, define $\widetilde f_r(t) = f \ast Q_r(t)$ where $Q_r(t) = \widetilde{P_r(t)} = \frac{2r\sin t}{1-2r\cos t + r^2}$. We set $\widetilde f = \lim_{r\to 1^-} \widetilde f_r(t)$. We know that this limit exists a.e. and that $\widetilde f \in L^{1,w}(\Bbb T)$.

The hypothesis is that for some constant $C > 0$, $$|f(x) - f(y)| \le C|x-y|$$
for all $x,y \in I$. We want to show, for all $0 < \alpha < 1$, that $|\widetilde f(x) - \widetilde f(y)| \lesssim_\alpha |x-y|^\alpha$ for all $x,y\in I$.

$$\begin{align*}
|\widetilde f(x) - \widetilde f(y)| &= \lim_{r\to 1^-} |(f\ast Q_r)(x) - (f\ast Q_r)(y)|\\ &= \lim_{r\to 1^-} \left|\int_{\Bbb T} f(x-t) Q_r(t)\, dt - \int_{\Bbb T} f(y-t) Q_r(t)\, dt \right|\\
&= \lim_{r\to 1^-} \left|\int_{\Bbb T} (f(x-t) - f(y-t)) Q_r(t)\, dt \right|\\
&\le \lim_{r\to 1^-} \int_{\Bbb T} |f(x-t) - f(y-t)| |Q_r(t)|\, dt\\
&\le C |x-y| \lim_{r\to 1^-} \int_{\Bbb T} \left|\frac{2r\sin t}{1-2r\cos t + r^2} \right|\, dt\\
&\approx |x-y|\lim_{r\to1^-} (\log(r+1) - \log(r-1)) = \infty
\end{align*}$$

It seems we need more careful estimation since directly using the Lipschitzness of $f$ in the above inequalities does not produce the required bound. In view of [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3285814/if-d-is-bounded-and-f-is-alpha-h%C3%B6lder-continuous-then-f-is-also-beta), though, would it be enough to show that the integral above is finite and $\widetilde f$ is Lipschitz-continuous?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is exercise 1 in Katzelson, Harmonic Analysis at the end of section 2.1. There is hint there as well.

Comment: Maybe try to use Holder inequality on your 3rd last row, it will bump the $Q_r$ into something integrable by sacrificing a little power in $|x-y|$.